# How to change the ISO currency code in the Magento core?

Tags: currency, magento-1.9.3.6, currency-symbol

**This is not a duplicate question, I have a very rare problem.**

More than a year ago, the ISO currency code "**Belarusian Ruble**" changed. Previously it was "**BYR**", and now "**BYN**". Since then, there have been many updates to Magento, but the list of currencies and their codes has not changed.

Using the settings in the **admin panel** (**System > Manage Currency > Symbols** ), I can change the display of the currency ISO code at frontend, but inside in system it still wrong.

So I can not use payment solutions in my country, auto-renewal of exchange rates and many other things.

Please explain how to fix the wrong currency code in the Magento core?

Magento version CE 1.9.3.6

Answer (score 1):

Magento completely depends on Zend framework for currencies. The files defining the currencies are located in `lib/Zend/Locale/Data`. Edit `en.xml` add your currency in `currencies` section:

```
<currencies>
    ...
    <currency type="BYN">
        <displayName>Belarusian Ruble</displayName>
        <displayName count="one">Belarusian Ruble</displayName>
        <displayName count="other">Belarusian Rubles</displayName>
    </currency>
    ...
</currencies>
```

Edit your locale xml file too, I believe it is `be.xml`? Then you can set your symbol in `System > Manage Currency > Symbols`.

But **Beware**: You're editing core files. It's a bad practice, but I don't know any way to overwrite Magento `lib` files somewhere else. With this approach, If you update your Magento version, these changes will lost.